# How to traverse associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I'm finding it tricky to traverse associations in Active Admin.

In my application I have a SupportSession which appears on an Invoice. Through an association with SupportAllocation I can traverse up the chain to get the SupportRate(s) chargeable on a SupportSession. I can use these rates in calculations for the value of the invoice.

My models are:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :support_session

class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, optional: true
  belongs_to :support_allocation

class SupportAllocation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :support_sessions
  has_many :support_rates

class SupportRate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :support_allocation
```

I've created an Active Admin resource for Invoice where I'd like to do some calculations:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Invoice do

  index do
    selectable_column

    column 'Reference', :reference, :sortable => 'invoices.reference'
    column 'Raised', :created_at, :sortable => 'invoices.created_at' do |invoice|
      invoice.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end
    column 'Due by', :due_by, :sortable => 'invoices.due_by'

    column :value do |invoice|
      # The next line retrieves an array of SupportRate(s) associated with this SupportSession on this invoice
      invoice.support_session.support_allocation.support_rates.each do |support_rate|

      # If the current SupportSession's support_type matches the SupportRate's support_type
        if support_rate.support_type == invoice.support_session.support_type
          # Do some calculations based on the support_rate.price attribute, plus some other bits I've omitted
        end
      end
      # The next line returns the correct price but obviously it's too clumsy and doesn't do the match on support_type
      # invoice.support_session.support_allocation.support_rates[0].price
    end

    actions
  end

end
```

I can see that data is being retrieved correctly. I can also see it is an array. But if I try to do anything with it, e.g. print out support_rate.price within my 'If' condition, I just get (e.g. for the first record):

```
[#<SupportRate id: 3, support_type: "mentoring", price: 0.3e2, support_allocation_id: 2>, #<SupportRate id: 13, support_type: "study_skills", price: 0.45e2, support_allocation_id: 2>]
```

In this specific example, the matching support_type was 'study_skills' - I need to use that support_rate's price for my calculations.

I imagine the solution lies in doing some sort of loop through the array or matching rates, as I've attempted? Active Admin doesn't seem to like it though.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please elaborate `Active Admin doesn't seem to like it though.`. What's the error or unexpected result?

Comment: The unexpected result is in a code block, in the original post, shortly after "I just get (e.g. for the first record):"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by calling a query on the associations available (the find_by method):

```
Invoice.calculate_value(invoice.support_session.support_allocation.support_rates.find_by(support_type: invoice.support_session.support_type).price
```

I remembered that an association is an object so inherits all the usual query methods available to it.

In order to do the necessary calculations, I just created a custom function that I hand the values to, it then returns a calculated value:

```
column :value do |invoice|
      Invoice.calculate_value(invoice.support_session.support_allocation.support_rates.find_by(support_type: invoice.support_session.support_type).price, invoice.support_session.rounded_duration_mins)
    end
```